# GDPR consent dialog not showing

Tags: java, android, admob

I followed the guide on the Android docs but for some reason nothing is showing when i start my app.
I even tried logging the listeners but nothing is showing up in logcat.

I also changed the ad technology in admob setting to Custom set of ad technology providers, but still not working.

**My code**

```
 ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        ConsentInformation.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addTestDevice("6AE7D8950FE9E464D988F340C0D625B0");
        ConsentInformation.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).
                setDebugGeography(DebugGeography.DEBUG_GEOGRAPHY_EEA);
        String[] publisherIds = {""};
        consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus) {
                // User's consent status successfully updated.
                Log.d(TAG,"onConsentInfoUpdated");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(String errorDescription) {
                // User's consent status failed to update.
                Log.d(TAG,"onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo");
            }
        });

        form = new ConsentForm.Builder(this, privacyUrl)
                .withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
                        // Consent form loaded successfully.
                        Log.d(TAG,"form loaded!");
                        form.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormOpened() {
                        // Consent form was displayed.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormClosed(
                            ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {
                        // Consent form was closed.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
                        // Consent form error.
                        Log.d(TAG,"form error!");
                    }
                })
                .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
                .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
                .withAdFreeOption()
                .build();

        form.load();
```

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
   }



implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
```

**EDIT**

I tried it on a project which was pre android x and now it calls the listener `onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo`.

With following error message:

```
onFailedToUpdateConsentInfoCould not parse Event FE preflight response.
```

Searched a bit and found this could be because of an invalid pub id, but i'm certain i'm using the right one.

Comment: You forget to `form.show();` Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540976/google-consent-sdk)

Comment: @MD I call it in onConsentFormLoaded()

Comment: @MD but the listener is not being called for some reason, seems like the whole code is just skipped.

Comment: @MD does consent-library:1.0.7 support Android X? Because i migrated to it.

Comment: @MD opened a project pre android x and then it does call a the listener onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo but not on my project with android X

Answer (score 0):

**1)** I think you forget to check `isRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown()` method. 
It will return true If user already agreed to the consent. In this case, you don't need to ask it again. I think you already agreed to consent.

wrap your code with

```
if(ConsentInformation.getInstance(context).isRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown()){
     //setup admob
}else{
     //Ask for consent
}
```

**2)** You have to call `form.show();` to present the form to the user, check [Google Doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/eu-consent#show_consent_form)

Comment: I call it in onConsentFormLoaded()

Comment: does consent-library:1.0.7 support Android X? Because i migrated to it. I tried it on a project pre android x and now it calls onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo  but gives error message onFailedToUpdateConsentInfoCould not parse Event FE preflight response.

Answer (score 0):

I was still using test app id and test ad ids, remove them and change it with your id's and make sure you use it as a testdevice so you don't violate admob policies.

Like this

```
   adLoader.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build());
```