# CCPA Detect Do not track, Google Account Web & App Activity Off

Tags: android, do-not-track

For the up coming CCPA [California Consumer Privacy Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Consumer_Privacy_Act) I need to detect the device settings for **Do Not Track** or **Opt out of Ads Personalization**.

Is there a way to detect these inside of my app? Does Google provide an API call?

To Find the settings

1. Go to the Settings app.
2. Tap on Google settings.
3. Tap Google Account (Info, security & personalization)
4. Tap on the Data & personalization tab.
5. Tap on Web & App Activity.
6. Toggle Web & App Activity off.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to do this? I added a bounty to your question because I am also researching this.

Comment: Update: I found most of what I needed in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540976/google-consent-sdk - if somebody wants to write up a summary in order to answer this question I still have 5 more days to award the bounty I put on this question . . .

Answer (score 1):

For now, Google didn't add the consent form for CCPA in SDK. However, you can use personalized ads by taking consent from a user by a custom consent form. Before requesting an ad you need to pass a parameter in AdRequest, this is the same way we are passing a parameter for GDPR compliance.

```java
Bundle networkExtrasBundle = new Bundle();
networkExtrasBundle.putInt("rdp", 1);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, networkExtrasBundle)
.build();
```

You can get some more details from here 
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/ccpa

Comment: Is 0 a valid option? 

Can we send networkExtrasBundle.putInt("rdp", 0); for personalized ads?